# Serverside redirect from iframe not working in Firefox and Chrome but works in IE6

Tags: php, html, http, redirect, iframe

I would love to know why the following does not work in Firefox 21 and Chrome 26 yet it works in IE 6.

I have a page "frame.html" which contains an iframe.

The iframe points to another page "post.html".

post.html contains a form which POSTs a username to a server php page "redirect.php".

The server responds with a redirect to google.

In IE6 the Google page appears in the iframe, but in Firefox and Chrome it doesn't.

Does anyone know why this happens and if it's even possible in a modern browser?

Thanks.

**frame.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Frame</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe width="800" height="800" src="post.html"/></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**post.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Post</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://myserver.com/redirect.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username"/>
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**redirect.php**

```
<?php header('Location: http://www.google.com'); exit; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers have cross domain protection builtin.

For instance. Google Chrome logs this message to the console:

```
Refused to display 'http://www.google.nl/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

If you would use a page that is on your domain it will work.

Comment: +1. It's worth adding the obvious point that this works in IE6 because IE6 doesn't have modern security features, and thus leaves its users wide open to being hacked. That's why you should stop using it (and stop supporting it in your site).

Comment: i'm using all the files from my localhost...still redirection not working in IE.